# php "require_once" includes file twice and fails | htaccess mod rewrite active

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, require-once

I use require_once  in different files.
After applying .htaccess redirect rules it still worked flawlessly on localhost but stopped working on the server.

I deleted a require_once line and then it also worked on the server.
The two directives that do include the file

```
require_once __DIR__.'/myfile.php';
require_once 'ECCO/CONF/myfile.php';
```

What could be the issue? Is htaccess redirect a known issue for include? 
The .htaccess files are not identical and on localhost there is a directory in the URL

```
localhost/dir/<redirect part ... >
```

eg

```
localhost/dir/EN/page/add/
```

or

```
sub.mydomain.com/<redirect part>
```

eg

```
sub.mydomain.com/EN/page/add/
```

The question might be too vaguely phrased and as it works it is low priority. However, a require_once should not conflict IMHO.

htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName &quot;Password Protected Area&quot;
AuthUserFile ../../htpasswd
Require valid-user
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|.ttf|.woff|woff2|.php)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/].*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What's the actual error you are seeing?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare newHTMLobject() (previously declared in /home/piquest1/ECCO/CONF/newHtmlObject.php:8) in /home/piquest1/ECCO/CONF/newHTMLobject.php on line 48

Comment: The .htaccess file wouldn't be causing this error unless the file you're including is including a duplicate file.

Comment: before I used htaccess it worked without error.

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file so we can see what is going on.

Comment: The server might be case sensitive for file names but your local env isn't? Can you check the actual filenames vs the file names used in your code and ensure they match?

Comment: the filenames are as is and match (ubuntu). It is case sensitive.